# How to specify position of an UIImage initWithImage to detect collision of the images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have looked up all related questions to this question but nothing brought success.
The problem is probably pretty simple:

I want to detect a collision between two geometrical objects which are animated in a way they are hitting eachother at a given time.

In order to use the method CGRectIntersectsRect i have to init the UIImage excactly with the size of the actual image of the geometrical object so it returns only a collision if the images/frames really collide.

So how do i specify the postion to place my image i have intiliazid with initWithImage.

I can't use the Method initWithFrame:CGRectMake as i do not want a UIImageview shaped as a rectangle.

Examples which do not work:

```
circleYellow = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height / 2, 50, 50)];
circleYellow.image = [UIImage imageNamed:images[arc4random() % 5]];


circleYellow = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:images[arc4random() % 5]]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you check out [cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/).  It has tools for handling sprites, updating their position through Actions (animations) on the screen, etc.

Detecting the collision of two sprites becomes something like:

```
-(void)update(float dt)
{
  CGRect rect1 = [sprite1 boundingBox];
  CGRect rect2 = [sprite2 boundingBox];

  if (CGRectIntersectsRect(rect1, rect2))
  {
      // Do something about the collision...
  }
}
```

And if you need more sophisticated modeling of the motion, or if you want to be able to collide arbitrary shapes and not just the bounding boxes, Box2D built in.  There are lots of examples available for this as well.

Was this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

UIImageView and it's superclass UIView always create rectangles. From the [UIView class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html):

> The UIView class defines a rectangular area on the screen ...

It sounds like SpriteKit may be what you need - check out the [sprite kit programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH6-SW14).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the SpriteKit:

```
//Create a SpriteNode loading your image
SKSpriteNode *cicleYellow = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:images[arc4random() % 5]];

//Set the size and the position of the Sprite
circleYellow.size = CGSizeMake(50,50);
circleYellow.position = CGPointMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height);

//Create a circlePhisicsBody and add it to the Sprite
SKPhysicsBody *circlePhisicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:cicleYellow.size.width/2.0f];
cicleYellow.physicsBody = circlePhisicsBody;
```

Check out the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH6-SW14) on how to use the Sprite Kit.

Answer (score 0):

You would need some timer function to check that every now and then but the algorihm for detecting collisions among Rectangles is pretty straight forward (square A and square B):

```
//If any of the sides from A are outside of B 
if( bottomA <= topB ) { return false; } 
if( topA >= bottomB ) { return false; } 
if( rightA <= leftB ) { return false; } 
if( leftA >= rightB ) { return false; } 
//If none of the sides from A are outside B return true;
```

If you need to do it for circles only here is a good tutorial: http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/when-worlds-collide-simulating-circle-circle-collisions--gamedev-769